# how to make factor level selectinput filed in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard, shinyjs

| sample | type | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sample1 | group1 | Male |
| sample2 | group1 | Female |
| sample3 | group1 | Male |
| sample4 | group2 | Female |
| sample5 | group2 | Female |

Suppose user have uploaded above csv file and data stored  as reactive object -  metadata() .
how can we create three selectinput fileds variable ,  condition1 and condition2 in dashboard,

such that varible filed show type and gender.

condition1  and condition2 fields show ; group1 and group2  (means all the levels of type) ; if user selects variable as type.

similarly condition1  and condition2 fields show ; Male and Female  (means all the levels of gender) ; if user selects variable as gender.

please help